# mysql for python 2. 7 says Python v2.7 not found

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector-python

I have downloaded mysql-connector-python-1.0.7-py2.7.msi from MySQL site 
and try to install but it gives error that

**Python v2.7 not found. We only support Microsoft Windows Installer(MSI) from python.org.**

I am using Official Python v 2.7.3 on windows XP SP3 with MySQL esssential5.1.66

Need Help ???

Comment: Just download mysql-connector-python-1.0.7-py2.7 and install over mysql 5.1.66 essential

Comment: So, you didn't install Python then? Download the [python for windows installer](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi), run it first and then try installing the MySQL drivers.

Comment: And I also set C:\Python27 to Path variable and Sorry, I forget to mention but I already installed python 2.7.3

Comment: *How* did you install Python. If you did not use the installer from python.org; then the correct registry entries would not have been written - which is why the MySQL installer is complaining.

Comment: I installed from python.org . All other python frameworks are working and python is also working good.Only this problem persists.

Comment: Download [this installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/b76p4jz8/MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe) and try it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Solution I get for this problem is

I have found Adding Python to Registry, the script as follows applicable for python v 2.0 and above:
 Register a Python Interpreter

```
#
# script to register Python 2.0 or later for use with win32all 
# and other extensions that require Python registry settings
#
# written by Joakim Low for Secret Labs AB / PythonWare
#
# source:
# http://www.pythonware.com/products/works/articles/regpy20.htm

import sys
from _winreg import *

# tweak as necessary

version = sys.version[:3]
installpath = sys.prefix
regpath = "SOFTWARE\\Python\\Pythoncore\\%s\\" % (version)
installkey = "InstallPath"
pythonkey = "PythonPath"
pythonpath = "%s;%s\\Lib\\;%s\\DLLs\\" % (
    installpath, installpath, installpath)


def RegisterPy():
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath)
    except EnvironmentError:
        try:
            reg = CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath)
            SetValue(reg, installkey, REG_SZ, installpath)
            SetValue(reg, pythonkey, REG_SZ, pythonpath)
            CloseKey(reg)
        except:
            print "*** Unable to register!"
            return
        print "--- Python", version, "is now registered!"
        return

    if (QueryValue(reg, installkey) == installpath and
            QueryValue(reg, pythonkey) == pythonpath):
        CloseKey(reg)
        print "=== Python", version, "is already registered!"
        return

    CloseKey(reg)
    print "*** Unable to register!"
    print "*** You probably have another Python installation!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RegisterPy()
```

Save it with any name.
Run it from python interpreter and Thats ALL!!

Answer (score 10):

I met the similar problem under Windows 7 when installing `mysql-connector-python-1.0.7-py2.7.msi` and `mysql-connector-python-1.0.7-py3.2.msi`.

After changing from `"Install only for yourself"` to `"Install for all users"` when installing Python for windows, the `"python 3.2 not found"` problem disappear and `mysql-connector-python-1.0.7-py3.2.msi` was successfully installed.

I guess the problem is that mysql connector installer only looks for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` entries, and the things it looks for might be under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` etc. So the solution that change the reg table directly also works.

Comment: Still relevant for connector v2.0.1. Reinstalling Python `"For all users"` fixed the problem.

Comment: This works for me as well ("install for all users") on windows7 using python 3.4.

Answer (score 7):

This problem mainly comes with 64 bit windows. download MySQL for python 64 bit on this link http://www.codegood.com/archives/129 and download  **MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe (1.0 MiB)** 
This will install MySQL for python.

**Windows 10 (64bit):**
Indeed, I've had a similar issue and couldn't install the python 2.7 connector for MySQL.

Prior to this I've installed `Python 2.7.15` with the [`Windows x86-64 MSI installer`](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi),
this was while I had `Python 3` installed on my machine.

The [`Windows x86 MSI installer`](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.msi) did the trick, I've installed it to *override* the previous version of Python 2.7.15, then installed the connector (this time it gave no error messages).

Then rechecked the status in the MySQL installer and voilà:
[image: Python27 connector recognized]

Comment: This answer provides a good choice to select the working version of mysql-python 2.7 in X64.

Answer (score 4):

If you're still experiencing this with `x64` or other python modules, I'd recommend this website [Python Extensions for x64/x32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I use Python only from within [SPSS](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-what-is-it/). I resolved this problem by manually adding two registry keys:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath`

set to

`C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath`

set to

`C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Python\Lib`

This easily fixed the issue on my previous as well as current laptops.

Comment: This inspired me and leads to my solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you download the version with the correct "bitness" (32/64 bit), matching the "bitness" of your Python installation!

I ran into the same problem (with Python 3.7.2, though).

I had Python 3.7.2 **32 bit** already installed, but accidentally downloaded the **64 bit** version of the MySQL Connector for Python 3.7.

When I tried to install the connector, I got the same error message:

[image: error message]

Solution: I just downloaded the 32 bit version instead, and everything worked (installing the connector and actually connecting to the database)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed python 2.7.14 x64 only for my user. I have to look for this  in my registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python
```

, export them, open the exported `.reg` file with a text editor, replace all occurrence of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, and import it.

The result is: (remember to change the install dir to yours)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Help\Main Python Documentation]
@="D:\\Desarrollo\\entornos\\python27_x64\\Doc\\python2714.chm"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="D:\\Desarrollo\\entornos\\python27_x64\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\InstallGroup]
@="Python 2.7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\Modules]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="D:\\Desarrollo\\entornos\\python27_x64\\Lib;D:\\Desarrollo\\entornos\\python27_x64\\DLLs;D:\\Desarrollo\\entornos\\python27_x64\\Lib\\lib-tk"
```

And the installation afterwards is smooth as a breeze. Viola!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using 32bit python