# Unable to install MySQL Connector/Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am using windows 64 bit and the installer file shows the error as 'Python v2.7 not found.We only support Python installed using the MSI downloaded from http://wwww.python.org/download'

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702146/mysql-for-python-2-7-says-python-v2-7-not-found

Comment: Read the question stil didn't get the answer

Answer (score 0):

before i migrated to python 3.4 from 2.7, i have used MySQLdb instead. and it worked:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

or

> pip install MySQL-python

Answer (score 0):

Create this key in windows registry, should be fine:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="c:\Python27\"